# Reading multiple paramters from same line using sscanf( )

Tags: c, linux, scanf

I had modified some code in C. I use mingw with gnu gcc compiler and Codeblocks as IDE. The code compiles and works well in this. But, when I try to run the code in a remote linux server, or actually any linux system it doesn´t. It compiles all right but execution is the problem. 
I give the part of code what I think is relevant:

```
short ReadNumRuns(FILE* File_Ptr)
{
  char buf[STRLEN];
  short n=0;

  FindDataLine(File_Ptr); /* skip file version. */

  strcpy(buf, FindDataLine(File_Ptr));
  if(buf[0]=='\0') nrerror("Reading number of runs\n");
  sscanf(buf, "%hd",&n);
  printf("%s", buf);
   printf("Number of runs: %hd ", n);
  return(n);
}

void ReadFnameFormat(FILE *File_Ptr, InputStruct *In_Ptr)
{
  char buf[STRLEN];

  /** read in file name and format. **/
  strcpy(buf, FindDataLine(File_Ptr));
  printf("%s", buf);
  if(buf[0]=='\0')
    nrerror("Reading file name and format.\n");
  sscanf(buf, "%s %c",In_Ptr->out_fname, &(In_Ptr->out_fformat) );
  printf("%s", In_Ptr->out_fname);
  printf("%c", In_Ptr->out_fformat);
  if(toupper(In_Ptr->out_fformat) != 'B')
    In_Ptr->out_fformat = 'A';
 }
```

These two functions are to read the number of runs and the the output file name. The first function works, but the second doesn't. From here on, the further input functions seem to skip lines. I'm guessing its because sscanf reads two parameters from the same line in this function.Is there any difference in sscanf in linux gcc and gnu gcc compilers? Thanks in advance.

If you want to look at the full code go to http://omlc.ogi.edu/software/mc/ and the the MCML part.

Comment: What is the (begining of the) content of the file and what do the two functions output on that content?

Comment: For someone to see the issue firsthand, it would be helpful if you write a tiny demo main() that calls these functions, and supply a sample data file that together demonstrate the problem.  Sometimes the act of writing the demo program itself brings the issue to light & you might solve your problem yourself.

Comment: The beginning of the input file contains some text that starts with '#'. There are other functions to ignore lines that start with # or the first character is '\0'. The first line that is read into a variable is the number of runs.
Not bale to put in a sample input file as I'm not yet allowed to answer my own questions here.

Comment: Ok, will write a separate main to call these parts. Thanks.